# How to re-add a panel?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to add code to a Back Button. I use a database table to keep track of pages(in form of panels) added. However once removed, adding the panel again does not seem possible. the code I have tried here:

```
Private Sub Back() Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
    Dim ctrl As System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    Dim ctrl2 As System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    '
    'Code to remove the current panel
    '
    For Each ctrl In ParentPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)
        If ctrl.Name <> "" Then
            ParentPanel.Controls.Remove(ctrl)
            '
        End If
    Next
    '
    'Code to get the name of the previous panel
    '
    Dim dmm As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT PageName FROM PagesHistory WHERE PageID = (SELECT Max(PageID)-1 FROM PagesHistory)", Con)
    dmm.Connection.Open()
    Dim rdd As String = dmm.ExecuteScalar
    '
    'Code to add the previous panel using its name
    '
    For Each ctrl2 In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)
        If ctrl2.Name = rdd Then
            ParentPanel.Controls.Add(ctrl2)
        End If
    Next
    dmm.Connection.Close()

End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Me.Controls` collection does not contain the deleted panels any more. Also, you would have to loop the `ParentPanel.Controls` collection instead of the `Me.Controls` collection.

A possibility to make it work, would be to make the panels invisible, instead of removing them:

```
ctrl.Visible = False
```

Then you can re-add it with:

```
ParentPanel.Controls(rdd).Visible = True
```

Note that you can a control by name from the `Controls` collection. See: [Control.ControlCollection.Item() Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.item?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Item_System_String_)

---

If you don't want to work with the `Visible` property, then you will have re-create the panel:

```
ParentPanel.Controls.Add(new MyPanel())
```

or you could keep a reference to the panels in a `Dictionary(Of String, Panel)` with the panel name as key. Then you can get the panel with

```
ParentPanel.Controls.Add(panelDictionary(rdd))
```

Comment: I thought so even though i did not try it. but how comes I have been able to add using ``` ParentPanel.controls.add(Panel1) ``` where Panel1 is the name i have given it in the ```FriendWithEvents``` Declaration?

Comment: Let me try the solution... Thanks in advance

Comment: If `Panel1` is the name of the panel (i.e. a type name), this does not work. If `Panel1` is a variable name, this could work.

Comment: Thanks Man it's worked, with new problems tho! Wonder is there is a better way to code a "Back Button"